# Delete HTML Table Row using Javascript

Tags: asp.net, javascript, html

I am using below code to delete HTML Table row using javascript but its giving me error.

using below code i am creating a column at run time using javascript which contains delete Anchor tag.

```
            var tbody = document.getElementById("<%= tblcriteria.ClientID %>").getElementsByTagName("TBODY")[0];

var row = document.createElement("TR")
 var td4 = document.createElement("TD");
 var code = "<a href=\"javascript:deleteCriteria(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);\">delete</a>";
    td4.setAttribute("align", "center");
    td4.innerHTML = code;
   row.appendChild(td4);
  tbody.appendChild(row);
```

Below function i am using to delete current row of html table:

```
function deleteCriteria(i) {
        if (window.confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this record?') == true) {
            document.getElementById("<%= tblcriteria.ClientID %>").deleteRow(i);

        }
    }
```

its giving me below error:

```
'this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex' is null or not an object
```

Please tell me where i am making mistake...

Comment: You might want to look into jQuery - http://jquery.com/ - for much easier DOM manipulation and cross browser support.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`this` does not point to the `<a>` element, but to the window.

Comment: Use onclick instead. You could still use an <a> element, or you could use an image.

Answer (score 2):

As @Sjoerd has mentioned you should use `onClick` instead.

This line

`var code = "<a href=\"javascript:deleteCriteria(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);\">delete</a>";`

should read

`var code = "<a href=\'#\' onclick=\'javascript:deleteCriteria(this.parentNode.parentNode.rowIndex);\'>delete</a>";`

Comment: No point in the `javascript:` label if you're using `onclick`.