# Deleting a row from an HTML table in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have javascript code that manages an HTML table.  The code needs to be able to delete a row from an HTML table.

I am currently using the following code to delete the row:

```
var rowToDelete = ...;

if (rowToDelete)
    rowToDelete.remove();
```

This works fine in Firefox & Chrome, however, when I load the page in IE 11 & bring up the javascript debugger, it displays

> Object doesn't support property or method 'remove'

I haven't tried this code in earlier versions of IE yet.

How can I do this in a cross-browser manner?  My page does have jQuery included so I can use a jQuery method.

Comment: what is `rowToDelete`? is it a dom element or jQuery wrapper object

Comment: Is `rowToDelete` a jQuery object, or a node?

Comment: `...`? in `var rowToDelete = ...;`

Comment: show us the full code please.

Comment: It is a Node element. Chrome supports `.remove()` on elements. He should do `rowToDelete.parentNode.removeChild(rowToDelete);`

Comment: rowToDelete is the HTML row / dom element.

Comment: @A1rPun that's the answer, post it below

Comment: Can you post your actual javascript and html? Also, see this question .. it's the same issue (error:not an object...) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3082609/delete-html-table-row-using-javascript?rq=1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your rowToDelete is an jQuery Object, like this:

```
var rowToDelete = $('tr');
rowToDelete.remove();
```

Comment: rowToDelete was a DOM element, but I did have easy access to a jQuery object for the same DOM element without having to call jQuery again to get one.  This works.  Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

Chrome supports `.remove()` on elements.
You should do:

```
rowToDelete.parentNode.removeChild(rowToDelete);
```

If you want this functionality in IE you can add the function to the HTMLElement prototype.

```
HTMLElement.prototype.remove = function (){
    this.parentNode.removeChild(this);
}
```

Comment: sorry, did not understand at the first instance.. +1 for this

Comment: Interestingly, FF doesn't seem to return the removed element like Chrome does. I'm pretty sure the spec requires this. I'll have to go back and check.

Comment: ...looks like `undefined` is the correct result. I guess it makes sense since you'd already have the node.

Answer (score 0):

If it is a dom element you can do

```
$(rowToDelete).remove();
```